# Call friend member of a class inside another class failed

Tags: c++

I thought adding `friend` will make a function visible and accessible inside a member function of another class but it failed. This is a minimal working example that shows the scenario

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
    public:
      A() { }
      void print(std::string str);
};

class B {
    public:
       B() { }
       friend void A::print(std::string);
       void set(std::string str);
};

void A::print(std::string str) 
{ 
    std::cout << str << std::endl; 
}

void B::set(std::string str) 
{ 
    A::print(str); // <--  error: ‘print’ was not declared in this scope
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    B b;
    b.set("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Majority of examples I've found out pass an object of class A as an argument to a member function of a class B but I couldn't find something similar to my problem. How the above code can be fixed without using `static`?

Comment: Try `A::A().print(str); ` You don't need `friend` in this case either

Comment: To call a non-`static` member function, it is necessary to have an instance of `A` and call it something like `an_a.print(str)` or `pointer_to_an_a->print(str)`.   Calling it without the object is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`friend` means, that the specific function or `class`/`struct` has `private` visibility. This means, it has full access to all your members. That doesn't do much in your case, but should never be done without a good reason.

I think, what you are looking for, is the `static` keyword.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
    public:
      A() { }
      static void print(std::string str);
};

class B {
    public:
       B() { }
       void set(std::string str);
};

void A::print(std::string str) 
{ 
    std::cout << str << std::endl; 
}

void B::set(std::string str) 
{ 
    A::print(str); // <--  error: ‘print’ was not declared in this scope
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    B b;
    b.set("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Didn't saw, that the question was without usage of static. I don't know, whats wrong with static in that case, but you can either declare print as a free function, or create an instance of A and call print this way.

```
void B::set(std::string str) 
{
    A a;
    a.print(str);
}
```

There is no other solution for you. You have to specify your need exactly.